# I want regular expression for validating decimal number and doesn't allow value 0.00

Tags: asp.net, validation, textbox

I'm uaing following regular expression for validating decimal or numeric (18,3) numbers, 
it does disallow users from entering more than 1 decimal points and all that

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="txtqty"  ValidationExpression="^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*([?[0-9]+)?$" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but i also want to disallow users from entering any value equal to 0 like the following eg:

0.00,
0000.00,
00.0,
0...

Comment: Then you should better use Custom Validator in this case

Comment: Why not add a RangeValidator to the page?

Comment: @podiluska I did try a range validator, but it doesnt work in few cases

Comment: range validotor works http://stackoverflow.com/a/11609617/1445836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using one validator to perform more than one task

Divide your problem:

- Validate the format
- Validate specific values

Use a simple `CompareValidator` in addition to your `RegularExpressionValidator`

```
<asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="Value must be grater than 0" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    runat="server" Operator="NotEqual" Type="Double" ValueToCompare="0" />
```

Comment: we can write a regex that can check for such values. I also use such kind of regex in amount fields to disallow amount before decimal in a way: 00.00 or 01234.34

Comment: I don't doubt it. But maintain your code will be a real PITA. When you can simplify things by a simple separation of concerns approach (SRP)

Answer (score 1):

"Use following regular expression:

```
^\d[1-9]*(\.\d+)|([0-9])$
```

it disallow values in following pattern:

```
00.00,0123.78 i.e value before decimal followed by 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used this

```
^([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="txtqty" MaximumValue="99999" MinimumValue="1.0000" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

range validator works